# CSS Hover class not copied correctly

Tags: css

Here's the JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/Kwk9p/

I'm basically trying to copy the `:hover` state to a static class, I've tried to no avail.

On the JSFiddle you can see I've added another class called `.activeConsole` this is the class I'm trying to use as the static `:hover` class, Although the border appears white and the text remains greyed out, I need the complete `:hover` style if possible?

Comment: trying to copy the static class ... like once they `:hover` the styling remains on the element?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I'm not fussed if the `:hover` remains once the static class is added, I just want to use the `:hover` style as a form of **active** class

Comment: well then comma separate it. `.whatever:hover, .whatever:active {}`

Comment: @PlantTheIdea, I can't seem to get the complete styling from the `:hover`, Could you simply compile a class for me with the complete CSS for the `:hover` class? as that's what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly (you want the first item to look all the time like the other ones while hovered?), but here you go:

```
ul.boxed-navigation li.active {
    background: #e70c2f;
    border-color: #e70c2f;
}

ul.boxed-navigation li.active a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thosetinydreams/d7vbd/).